# Receber uma string de uma matriz PHP para uma variável JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, matriz, funções

Tenho uma matriz em PHP com uma determinada string,
 Ex.:

```
 $matriz[2][2] = "texto"`.
```

Daí eu quero passar essa matriz para uma variável em JavaScript.

Ex.:

```
`var v_php = "<?php echo $matriz[2][2]; ?>";`
```

Quando exibo o conteúdo na tela, está tudo ok. 
Ex.:

`document.write(v_php);`

Mas quando faço uma condição/comparação com outra variável JS vindo de um INPUT HTML, 
aí o resultado é sempre falso, independente do que esteja dentro de cada string.

Código completo:

```
    <?php $matriz[2][2] = "texto"; ?>

<input type="text"   id="id_field" value=""/>
<input type="button" id="corrige"  value="VERIFICAR" onclick="funcButton()" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function funcButton(){

        var v_js  = document.getElementById("id_field").value;
        var v_php = "<?php echo $matriz[2][2]; ?>" ;

        // Verificando as strings
        document.write(v_js);
        document.write(v_php );

        if ( v_js == v_php ){
          alert('Variáveis Idênticas.');
        }else{ 
               alert('Variáveis Diferentes');
             } 
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Testei o código e funcionou, se escrever "texto" ele faz o alert 'Variáveis Idênticas.'

Comment: Realmente não tem erro. O código funcionou aqui também.

Comment: Verdade, na verdade eu tentei mostrar um exemplo para incurtar o código, mas o problema é que essa Matriz, vem de um select do banco de dados e logo após a mesma é randomizada com "shuffle". Só depois que esse dados é atribuído a variável JS. Devido a tudo isso, deve ter algum erro na conversão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passe a matriz como json com a função [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php):

`<script type="text/javascript">`
`// passando a matriz do php para o javascript`
`var matriz = <?php echo json_encode( $matriz ) ?>;`
`// acessando a matriz no JavaScript`
`console.log( matriz[2][2] ); // texto`
`</script>`

Comment: Perfeito meu caro, com json_encode funcionou perfeitamente! Irei estudar um pouco sobre o mesmo, pois gostaria de entender o pq de funcionar com ele. Obrigado!